# launching asp.net core prject in VSC2019 is not working

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm just started following a tutorial on ASP.NET Core.

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.35.1 and created a new project using the `dotnet new webapp` command. But when I start the project, the home page doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean doesnt work ? Please be more clear . What is the error, screen shot etc ...

Comment: when i satrt the project it redirects me to https://localhost:5001, but it shows this error :ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Comment: You forgot to configure .NET Core certificate (it must be configured and trusted by your computer before moving on).

Comment: Try `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` , and then 
     `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`